# Reading from usb device using node-usb

Tags: node.js, usb, electron

I am trying to read data from a USB device "connected to my PC" using [tessel/node-usb](https://github.com/tessel/node-usb) in my electron application
but i am not able to read anything or getting any error !
i am using following js :

```
function connectdevice(vID, pId){
var device = usb.findByIds(vID, pId);
device.open();
var deviceINTF=device.interface(0);

if (deviceINTF.isKernelDriverActive())
    deviceINTF.detachKernelDriver();
deviceINTF.claim();


var ePs = deviceINTF.endpoints;
var epIN;
$.each( ePs, function( index, ep ){
    if(ep.direction=="in"){
        epIN=ep;
}
});
if(epIN){
    epIN.on('data', function (data) {
        alert("1"+data);
    });
    epIN.transferType = 2;
    alert("non empty port : "+epIN);
    epIN.transfer(64, function(error, data) {
        console.log(error, data); 
    });
    alert("after transfer");
}else{
    alert("unable to read .."); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code has no issue but my device has 2 interfaces , and my code checking the first interface when i change this line code :

```
var deviceINTF=device.interface(0);
```

to :

```
var deviceINTF=device.interface(1);
```

It works !

Hope this help anybody.